# General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value with Doctrine 2.1 and Zend Form update

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-form

I am processing a submitted Zend Form which updates a Doctrine Record using the following code, where $query is a query built using a doctrine query builder:

```
$record_array = $query->getResult();
$this->_record = $record_array[0];
if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
    {
        if ($this->_form->isValid($this->_request->getPost()))
        {
            $newEntity = $this->_form->update($this->_record);
            $this->_em->flush(); 
            $this->view->success = 'Record Saved.';
        } else {
            $this->view->errors = $this->_form->getErrors();
        }        
    }
```

The above works fine if there are no integers in the record, i.e. only strings.  However, I get the error above if I include fields on the form which are mapped as integers in the doctrine entity.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
/**
 * @var integer $solicitorid
 *
 * @Column(name="SolicitorID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @Id
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $solicitorid;

/**
 * @var string $solicitor
 *
 * @Column(name="Solicitor", type="string", length=160, nullable=true)
 */
private $solicitor;

/**
 * @var string $address
 *
 * @Column(name="Address", type="string", length=160, nullable=true)
 */
private $address;

/**
 * @var string $town
 *
 * @Column(name="Town", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $town;

/**
 * @var string $county
 *
 * @Column(name="County", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $county;

/**
 * @var string $postcode
 *
 * @Column(name="Postcode", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $postcode;

/**
 * @var string $dxaddress
 *
 * @Column(name="DXAddress", type="string", length=150, nullable=true)
 */
private $dxaddress;

/**
 * @var string $phone
 *
 * @Column(name="phone", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @var string $fax
 *
 * @Column(name="fax", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
 */
private $fax;

/**
 * @var string $email
 *
 * @Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string $password
 *
 * @Column(name="password", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var integer $leadStatus
 *
 * @Column(name="lead_status", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $leadStatus;

/**
 * @var string $termsref
 *
 * @Column(name="termsRef", type="string", length=10, nullable=true)
 */
private $termsref;

/**
 * @var integer $termsconditions
 *
 * @Column(name="termsconditions", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $termsconditions;

/**
 * @var date $termssent
 *
 * @Column(name="termsSent", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $termssent;

/**
 * @var date $termssigneddate
 *
 * @Column(name="termssigneddate", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $termssigneddate;

/**
 * @var integer $paymentterms
 *
 * @Column(name="paymentterms", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $paymentterms;

/**
 * @var integer $discountterms
 *
 * @Column(name="discountterms", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $discountterms;

/**
 * @var float $discountrate
 *
 * @Column(name="discountrate", type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $discountrate;

/**
 * @var integer $accountscontact
 *
 * @Column(name="AccountsContact", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $accountscontact;

/**
 * @var date $warned
 *
 * @Column(name="warned", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $warned;

/**
 * @var float $feerate
 *
 * @Column(name="FeeRate", type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $feerate;

/**
 * @var string $labourrate
 *
 * @Column(name="LabourRate", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $labourrate;

/**
 * @var text $specialinst
 *
 * @Column(name="SpecialInst", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $specialinst;

/**
 * @var text $reportinst
 *
 * @Column(name="ReportInst", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $reportinst;

/**
 * @var boolean $autostatement
 *
 * @Column(name="AutoStatement", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $autostatement;

/**
 * @var datetime $lastmodifed
 *
 * @Column(name="lastModifed", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $lastmodifed;
```

Above is the entity.
The issue comes when I try to update an integer field.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

are you using MySQL? this can happen because MySQL is running in strict mode.
run these queries from phpMyAdmin or whatever db administrator you are using to check if the database is in strict mode:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

if it returns something containing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` you could try and run:

```
SET @@global.sql_mode= 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: It did contain the strict_trans_tables, and your suggestion turned it off.
What effect does this actually have, why should it have been on in the first place?

Comment: this is pretty accurate: "In non-strict mode, the MySQL server converts erroneous input values to the closest legal values (as determined from column definitions) and continues on its way. For example, if you attempt to store a negative value into an UNSIGNED column, MySQL converts it to zero, which is the nearest legal value for the column." in strict mode it will directly skip those conversions and throw that error you are seeing. maybe you can post the mapping of the entity you are trying to update, and the actual data you are sending to it in your form

Comment: Been working for hours in trying to find this solution... for some reason my AWS RDS MariaDB instance have changed configuration. Thanks!