# MySQL running in Strict Mode and giving me problems. How to fix this?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a CSV I download from the State of Florida so I'm not in control over what's in the file.  There are some fields (such as price) that are sometimes null.  In my table where I'm importing these values, I marked sold_price as BIGINT, Unsigned, Allow Null and default of Null.  However, when I attempt to insert a NULL value (empty cell in the CSV), I get the error:

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'sold_price' at row 1
```

I followed the advice [in this answer someone posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874647/general-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value-with-doctrine-2-1-and-zend-form-upda/8882396#8882396) and that fixes the problem.  However, whenever MySQL is restarted, I get the error again and have to redo that query.

Also, I don't think that's the appropriate way to fix the problem, is it?  What should I be doing in cases where a field such as sold_price is null and I'm trying to insert it into a table?

I'm running MySQL version 5.6.13.

Comment: `''` is not an integer or null. it's an empty string, and since you're in strict mode, mysql won't auto-convert the empty string to a null or 0 or whatever else. it is not possible to represent an ACTUAL sql null in a csv file, so empty strings are the next best thing.

Comment: If you're running a PHP script you can check the fields for correct values and change the ones that give you an error. In practice, though, you should be doing this with `LOAD DATA INFILE` and making use of the editing facilities that provides.

Comment: I am a big fan of loading data first into a staging table, where all columns are large strings.  Then do the conversion inside the database, so you can see where the errors are.  As a plus, you can have a single query that does all the conversions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, that's somewhat what I'm doing.  I'm trying to put it into a staging table but I hadn't been doing everything as a string.  Very interesting thought.

Comment: You might consider using an opensource tool called http://heidisql.org/ for the first stage of loading. It does a decent job of grinding up csv files.

Comment: Just a general follow-up question but I could easily check to see if something like the field "full_baths" is '' and if it is, tell it to use a 0.  However, that is technically wrong since no home being sold has 0 baths.  It almost seems more correct for it to be NULL.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can disable the strict mode. In you my.ini-file you'll find something like

```
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Change that to:

```
sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at though is that do I really want to disable strict mode?  Pardon my ignorance here but it's there for a reason presumably and by getting rid of it, am I then setting myself up for future problems?

Comment: The answer to that question is "it depends" :). If you can think of a case where auto-conversion is not what you want then don't do it. On the other hand strict_mode was disabled as default until 5.5 (or 5.4?), so for a long time people could live without strict_mode. However, you can also always use the mysql-function "NULLIF" to replace empty strings with NULL-value: NULLIF('',yourvalue)

Comment: sorry, NULLIF(yourvalue, '') not NULLIF('', yourvalue)