# Incorrect integer value '' for a MySQL column that's integer and allow null?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on inserting a CSV into a table.  I don't have any control over what's in the CSV and a lot of the fields are blank.  In my very first record for instance, the field "baths_full" is just empty (two commas back to back).

On my production server running MySQL 5.5.37, it inserts the record with the `baths_full` as an empty field.  On my local machine running MySQL 5.6.19, it gives me the error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'baths_full' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `listings_queue` (`
```

The weird thing is that the schema for the tables is identical.  In fact, I used the export of the production machine to create the local database.

The field `baths_full` is set to TinyInt, unsigned, allow null, default null.  One thing to add is that it looks like in the SQL insert statement Laravel is creating, it is treating null values as spaces.  Regardless, my production machine runs the script without trouble but locally it won't run.

Comment: Are you running the same version of PHP and Laravel on local and production? i.e. is "mySQL" version the ONLY difference?

Comment: Can you provide some code where you process your CSV and the code that inserts it to the database?

Comment: Good points.  Local PHP is 5.5.13.  Production is PHP 5.5.13-2+deb.sury.org~precise+1.  As for the code, I've put some up at http://laravel.io/bin/21PnN.  Keep in mind, the CSV is sent to me by the state so I have no control over how big or what's in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found my problem.  My local MySQL is running in strict mode.  The answer from this thread ([General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value with Doctrine 2.1 and Zend Form update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874647/general-error-1366-incorrect-integer-value-with-doctrine-2-1-and-zend-form-upda/8882396#8882396)) fixed it.

Comment: MVP: Answering his own question when he found the answer

Answer (score 0):

If the database column already contains a value of different data type not the same with the one you are changing to can throw error 1366, for example if a string value is already in one column of the table you are changing to tinyint. I once ran into this.

Answer (score -3):

why not try type casting it to integer before inserting?

```
array( 'baths_full' => (int) $baths_full, ... )
```

like

```
"VALUES(".((int) $baths_full).")"
```

Comment: Well, I'm using Laravel and it handles the insert automatically.  I'm not doing raw SQL.

Comment: Then use the first one, before using the insert function (whatever it is)